# Grails 3.0.9 and Jobs

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.0.9

I want install Job in Grails 3.0.9: 
[Grails Quartz](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz)

I add compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.1' in build.gradle and I have error:

```
Warning:<i><b>root project 'example': Web Facets/Artifacts will not be configured properly</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
 (org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/quartz/2.0.1/quartz-2.0.1.zip</i>
```

I know that there is no zip file in this repo.

Help me.

Comment: can you please include your `build.gradle` file? Gradle is trying to resolve the plugin in the old Grails 2.x repository